# Printing Arranged/Clear/Neat Document in VB

Tags: vb.net, document

I have to print the info that the customer inputs into the program in a special format (see image). I've got it so the customer can enter the information into a database,which they name.I just don't know how to put it in the special format as shown in the image. Do I do it in the code or on the document.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
    Imports System.IO

    Module Module1
    Dim userans As String
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to this program. Choose weather to view the database or add")
    userans = Console.ReadLine()
    If userans = "add" Then
        Dim objStreamwriter As StreamWriter
        Console.WriteLine("Please type in the name of your new file")
        Dim Myfilename As String = Console.ReadLine()
        objStreamwriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\Oliver\Documents\Computing\" + Myfilename + ".txt")
        Dim TextString = "" 'What you are passing to it.
        'Write a line of text to my file defined above
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the data. Type Quit at end")
        Console.WriteLine("Name ")
        Console.Read()
        Console.WriteLine("Adress line and number")
        Console.Read()
        Console.WriteLine("Town")
        Console.Read()
        Console.WriteLine("Postcode")
        Console.Read()


        TextString = Console.ReadLine()
        While TextString <> "Quit"
            objStreamwriter.WriteLine(TextString)
            TextString = Console.ReadLine()
        End While
        'Close the file.
        objStreamwriter.Close()
    End If
    If userans = "view" Then
        Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
        Dim strLine As String
        Dim filename As String
        Console.WriteLine("Please type in the name of the file to view.")
        filename = Console.ReadLine()
        'Pass the file path and the file name to the StreamReader constructor.
        objStreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\Oliver\Documents\Computing\WriteMrFox.txt")
        'Read the first line of text.
        strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine
        'Continue to read until you reach the end of the file.
        Do While Not strLine Is Nothing
            'Write the line to the Console window.
            Console.WriteLine(strLine)
            'Read the next line.
            strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine
        Loop
        objStreamReader.Close()
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```